# How do I connect to a production database from a Docker container?

Tags: docker

I'm trying to dockerize a node.js app that was previously running on Heroku with a postgres addon as a production database. Cannot connect to the database from the container.

**Docker file**

`FROM node:8
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["npm","start"]`

Docker Compose file

`version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
     - "5000:5000"
     - "5432:5432"
    env_file: .env
    extra_hosts:
      - "iondev:172.27.27.59"`

**The error**
`web_1  | {"level":30,"time":1553864230376,"msg":"Narrafy listening on port 5000","pid":16,"hostname":"961f47819c3e","v":1}
web_1  | {"level":50,"time":1553864230399,"msg":"Failed to connect to DB.","pid":16,"hostname":"961f47819c3e","v":1}
web_1  | {"level":50,"time":1553864230399,"msg":"Connection terminated unexpectedly","pid":16,"hostname":"961f47819c3e","type":"Error","stack":"Error: Connection terminated unexpectedly\n    at Connection.con.once (/usr/src/app/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:200:9)\n    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)\n    at emitNone (events.js:106:13)\n    at Connection.emit (events.js:208:7)\n    at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:130:10)\n    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)\n    at Socket.emit (events.js:208:7)\n    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)\n    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:139:11)\n    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)","v":1}`

Comment: Can you share the error message you're getting from your node app and your Dockerfile (without secrets)?

Comment: Get a shell on your container `docker run -it --entrypoint=bash <imagename>` and try a) to check if the target host/port is reachable from inside the container: `nc -zv -w 2 <db-host> 3306` b) try to manually connect to it; `mysql -u <username> -p<password> -p <databasename>`; you will need the corresponding tools on the container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without dockerfile it is not possible to debug this issue. Most probably check your DB creds and make sure you pass them as ENV variable.

You can check the logs using 
docker logs < container id >.

Or use docker exec command to check your environment variables.

Comment: In my .env file : I have something like 
DATABASE_URL=postgresql://172.27.27.59:5432/postgres